# Why does Backbone's collection create() method not populate the id?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

In my view's method below, my model gets synced with the server if I understand the `create()` method properly. However, the `console.log` of `this.model.id` still returns `undefined` and `this.model.isNew()` returns `true`. The POST shows an id in the return JSON object and the model object attributes show an id as well, so why are they not reflecting properly in the model? I need the id to be set when I create the new view.

```
submitForm: function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.model.set( this.$( '.editForm' ).serializeObject() );

  if ( this.model.isNew() )   {
    collection.create( this.model );

    console.log( this.model, this.model.id, this.model.isNew() );

    new MyView({
      model: this.model
    }).render().appendNode();
  }   else   {
    this.model.save();
  }

  this.closeForm();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting it for me @mu. SO wouldn't let me format my code properly... dunno what happened there.

Comment: No worries. You wanted to use the `{ }` button rather than then `"` button in the editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So Jacob, the problem here is just that before rendering your view, you need to wait the response from the server. Your `this.model.id` will be `undefined` because your model is new, that means that it was not saved in the server yet.

So, what you could do is to work with the `success` callback from the `.create` function. I believe that something like this would work for you.

```
if (this.model.isNew()) {
  collection.create({
    // or you can use this.model (if it is an object)
    attribute_x: 'val',
    attribute_y: 'val'
  }, success: function(response){
    // here your model with have an id
    console.log(response);
    new MyView({
      model: response.model // check your response
    }).render().appendNode();             
  });
} else {
  new MyView({
    model: this.model
  }).render().appendNode();
}
```

So, as you can see, in the `success` callback, we render the `View`. And if you `console.log` the response you'll see what your back-end responded to you in the creation of the model.

Comment: `{ this.model }` is invalid syntax, FYI.

Comment: I got the id from the response as expected using the success callback. Thanks @LeonardoR.!

Comment: @jacobroufa I'm glad that it was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you want, you can use the `{ wait: true }` option when invoking `create()`; that way, the model won't be added to the collection until after it's successfully saved.

Combining this with having the rest of your logic occur on the collection's `add` event should take you a long way, probably. If you need to be able to distinguish between newly `create`'d models and ones added to the collection later, you can add another option to the `create` call (something like `newlySaved: true`, and then check for `options.newlySaved` in the add event callback).

Comment: I think I need to reorganize more of my code for that to work, but thanks for clarification on the `wait` flag!